# Stacking commands on OSX Terminal: is the limit configurable somewhere?

Tags: macos, terminal

To replicate, open a Terminal tab and execute:

```
sleep 30
```

While the command execute, you can still stack commands which will execute in sequence when the sleeps terminates.

There seems to be a limit to this 'stack', if you try to paste multiple times the command:

```
echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

only around 13-14 of them will get stacked, hen the input is truncated.

Does anyone know if this is a configurable limit? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call "stacking" is actually the terminal driver's buffer. When you input commands, you are writing to the tty (/dev/ttys000x.. as shown by "tty" command). The shell opens the tty for input, and reads characters from it. when you make the shell sleep, you are preventing further characters from being read, and they get buffered. You can see terminal settings with "stty -a", and change some settings.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried changing rows and columns settings but had no effect on the behavior I described. Is there a specific setting I should touch? Cheers